# Fabric run not working with password

Tags: fabric, scp

I want to copy a file from **remote1** host to the **remote2** host using fabric. 
I am trying to pass the password for **remote2** to the fabric run command, but it's still prompting for the **remote2** password.

Anything wrong with my code?

```
run('echo "pass123" | scp my.tar root@1.2.3.4:')
run('"pass123" | scp my.tar root@1.2.3.4:')
```

**Edit:**
In our prod and stagging environments key auth is not supported.

Comment: In general it would be better to use a key authentication: https://www.debian-administration.org/article/530/SSH_with_authentication_key_instead_of_password . So you don't have to hardcode any passwords.

Comment: mistapink,  in our prod and stagging environments key auth is not supported. we have to give deployment scripts to admins and they suppose to run them using there credentials. my plan is the write a bash script which takes credentials from the user and pass them to the fabric scripts.

Comment: I see, then you probably just can try this: http://serverfault.com/questions/318474/how-to-pass-password-to-scp-command-used-in-bash-script. Otherwise you may could use something like `<<EOPASS password EOPASS`.

Comment: mistapink, sshpass is not installed in prod and stagging environments. can you explain me how to use <<EOPASS password EOPASS in the fab scripts

Comment: as I read from this answer: http://serverfault.com/a/132415 _If you intend to do it with (ba)sh scripts and use OpenSSH it gets harder. OpenSSH explicitly prevents you from putting passwords on the command line_. So even my suggested method will fail. I read there that there is something like [Expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) which might help you.

Answer (score 1):

The OpenSSH utilities, including `scp`, don't accept passwords on the command line or standard input. Whey they read a password, they explicitly open the process's TTY and read from that.

There are basically four approaches available to you:

1. Use key-based authentication instead of passwords.
2. Use a program like `sshpass` or `expect` to feed the password to `scp` through a PTY.
3. [Download the OpenSSH source code](http://www.openssh.com/portable.html) and modify the software to work the way you want.
4. Find a way to transfer these files which doesn't involve using the OpenSSH clients software.